# Python - Transform DataFrame for Merge

Tags: python, transform, melt

I have two different dataframes.

One looks like:

```
     Date          StoreID     MerchandiseType     Count
     04/01/2020    1           Hat                 2
     04/01/2020    1           Shirt               4
```

The other looks like:

```
     Date        StoreID     Hat    Shirt
     04/01/2020  1           2      4
```

I would like to transform dataframe 2, so that it is structured like dataframe 1 and then union. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'StoreID'], value_vars=['Hat', 'Shirt'])
```

This will give you the right format and then you can merge.

Output: 
[image]

Comment: No idea why I made it more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad to help!